# Equality of Radon measure

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ a Hausdorff locally compact topological space. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two Radon measures on $X$.
The following result is true ? Why ?

> if  $$ \forall \varphi \in C^{0}(X), \int{\varphi d\mu} = \int{\varphi d\nu}   $$ Then $\mu = \nu $

PS : I think I have a proof, but I used a theorem I don't know how to prove.

It is enough to show that 
$$
\forall \varphi \in C^{0}(X), \int{\varphi d\mu} = 0 \Rightarrow \mu = 0
$$
As $C_{c}^{0}$ (continuous function with compact support over $X$) are dense in $L^{1}$ it exists $\varphi_{n} \in C_{c}^{0} $ such as 
$$
|| \varphi_{n} - 1_{O} ||_{1} \rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0
$$
So $|\int{\varphi_{n}} - \mu(O)|\rightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty}  0 $ and $\mu(O)=0$

So do you think we can prove that $C_{0}^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^{n}$ ?

If we consider only $C_{0}^{0}$ I know a proof. It consists to approximate $1_{E}$ with $E$ a borel subset such as $\mu(E) <+\infty$ and use Urysohn. I need a trick to say that is enough to consider $E$ such as $\mu(E) <+\infty$, I don't see the trick now ^^.

Okay I asked you all my questions, thank you very much to have read me !

EDIT : I improved my topological assumptions, otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: You need some assumptions on $X$. Something like Uryshon's Lemma /Tietze extension Theorem us required.

Comment: Okay I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $X$ needs to be locally compact, otherwise it can happen that $C^0_c(X) = \{0\}$. For example if $0 \neq \varphi$ is a continuous function on some infinite dimensional Banach space $X$, then by continuity it is nonzero on some open subset of $X$, and hence does not have compact support. The zero space obviously does not separate Radon measures.

However, if $X$ is locally compact, you have [Riesz reprezentation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) which shows that $C_c^0(X)^* = M(X)$, where $M(X)$ is the set of all signed (or complex) Radon measures on $X$. Hence your result follows as space separates points of its dual.

Comment: You are right, I'll improve my assumptions.

Comment: Can you precise your theorem ? 1) Why $ \varphi$ does not have compact support and 2) I know a theorem $\forall x,y \in E, x\ne y \Rightarrow \exists \varphi \in E^{*} ; \varphi(x) \ne \varphi(y)$ but here $E = C_{c}^{0}$  so it didn't show me the proof.

Comment: 1) In infinite dimensional Banach spaces every set with nonempty interior fails to be compact. As shown, $\varphi$ is nonzero on some open set, hence its support has nonempty interior.
2) Here $E$ is $C_c^0(X)$ and $E^*$ is $M(X)$. The theorem  you know works the other way around as well, i.e. $\forall \mu \neq \nu \in E^* \exists f \in E: \int f d \mu = \mu(f) \neq \nu(f) = \int f d \nu$.